# Borromean Weaving

Tags: recreational-mathematics, knot-theory

Here's a picture by Rashmi Sunder-Raj.

[image]

Is this topologically equivalent to Borromean Rings?

Comment: It does seem that, if you remove one of the three, the other two are unlinked.

Comment: But having the property of being a Brunnian link is far from being the Borromean rings.  Am I correct that the question is "Is this link ambient isotopic to the Borromean rings?" Or are you just wondering if it is also Brunnian?

Comment: Since the link is Brunnian one could theoretically stretch out two of the knots as round unknots and then read off the free word given by how the third component travels through the first two. For the borromean rings it is the simplest possible commutator, but I imagine this one would be more complicated. It looks rather tedious to implement this though.